# Changeable variable in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, blackjack

I'm trying to create a simple game of Pontoon (similar to blackjack) and I have made a list of cards as a deck. My current build of the game works if I give ACE a value of 1 or 14, but I need it to have both values so if a hand goes over 21, ACE returns to 1.

```
deck = [ACE, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, ACE, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, ACE, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, ACE, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
```

So the basicly the card picking happens like this:

```
while True:
    hand = []
    hand.extend(random.sample(deck, 1))    
    print(hand)
    while True:
        hit = input("new card? (k/e)")
        if hit == "k":
            hand.extend(random.sample(deck, 1))
            print("")
            print("HAND:")
            print(hand)
            a = sum(hand)
            print("")
            print("SUM:")
            print(a)
            if a > 21:
                print("")
                print("OVER")
                break
            elif a == 21:
                print("")
                print("Pontoon")
                break
            else:
                continue
```

I have tried to make ACE as a function, but random.sample doesn't work with that

```
def ACE():
    if a > 21:
        A = 1
    else:
        A = 14
    return int(A)
```

So how do I get ACE to work as a 1 and a 14?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not change the value of a variable, you adjust your summing-function:

```
import random

ACE = 14
deck = [ACE, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 
        ACE, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 
        ACE, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 
        ACE, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]

import copy

def sumHand(hand):
    """ calculates the sum of cards in hand. if over 21 it will substitute
    14 with 1 as ACE can be both. If no 14 in hand or below 21 will return value"""

    k = hand.copy() # copy hand into k, so it will still show 14 but 
                    # you can sum up as few ACE as needed to be 1 wehn 
                    # calculating this sum

    # maybe change 14th to 1 if neeed be
    while sum(k) > 21 and ACE in k:
        k.remove(ACE) # remove  a 14
        k.append(1)   # replace by 1
    return sum(k)

while True:
    hand = [ACE,ACE] # start with 2 aces already for testing purposes
    hand.extend(random.sample(deck, 1))    
    print(hand)
    while True:
        hit = input("new card? (k/e)")
        if hit == "k":
            hand.extend(random.sample(deck, 1))
            print("")
            print("HAND:")
            print(hand)
            a = sumHand(hand)
            print("")
            print("SUM:")
            print(a)
            if a > 21:
                print("")
                print("OVER")
                break
            elif a == 21:
                print("")
                print("Pontoon")
                break
            else:
                continue
```

Output:

```
[14, 14, 8]
new card? (k/e)
HAND:
[14, 14, 8, 7]

SUM:
17
new card? (k/e)
HAND:
[14, 14, 8, 7, 5]

SUM:
22

OVER
```

Comment: This works but it shows the aces as 14 after they are replaced as 1. Do I need to make k global and replace the hand outputs as k?

Comment: @JussiMuussi  If you want to change the 14 to 1, simply change 
    `k = hand.copy()` to `k = hand`  (or simply remove `k` and operate directly on `hand` inside the sumHand-function) - the cards wont be replaces in-space though, the 14 are removed whereever they are, and added as 1 to the end of your hand. There is no need to make anything global _**shudder**_ - you then can also remove `import copy`

Answer (score -1):

You can do this by defining the ACE as a class

```
class ACE():
    value = 1
    def set_value(self, value):
        self.value = value
```

And then you can change the value of array element like this

```
ace = ACE() # in this step you have ace value = 1
array = [ace, 1, 2, 3, ...]
for a in array:
    if type(a) == type(ACE):
        # Your desired conditions
        a.set_value(14)
```